# How to get data from server by using JSON, JQuery and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, ajax

I am newer on developing flask-python based applications and got stuck in some point. The problem is that I cannot retrieve data from mysql.

First of all, let me share my some files' contents, at least some parts of them. For html, I am using bootstrap.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/search-bar.css">

    <script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-1.11.2.js') }}"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/wordQuery.js') }}"></script>  

  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="custom-search-input">
            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
              <input type="text" id="wordInput" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Please type the word you want to search" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" id="btnWordSearch">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                  </button>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, jsonify, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'USER_NAME'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'PASSWORD'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'DATABASE_NAME'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/wordQuery', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def checkWord():
    word = request.form['wordInput']
    success = "OK"
    error = "NOK"
    word = word.lower()
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Read a single record
            sql = "SELECT `word` FROM `allwords` \
                    WHERE `word` like %s"
            cursor.execute(sql, (word + "%",))
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result is not None:
                return json.dumps({'message': 'The word exists in the database !'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error': str(data[0])})
    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5005)
```

**wordQuery.js:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnWordSearch').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: '/wordQuery',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I want to see that when a word is searched, it should be found on the database and browser console should write the message 'The word exists in the database !'. Later, I want to implement another html page which gives results.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**

I was getting the below error when I first posted this problem here;

```
jquery-1.11.2.js:9659 POST 127.0.0.1:5005/wordQuery 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

However, now I changed a part in my html file. There was an `id` element like this: `id="wordInput"` and I changed it like this: `name="wordInput"`. After this change, I am getting a new error like this following;

```
jquery-1.11.2.js:9659 POST http://127.0.0.1:5005/wordQuery 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

Comment: I'm not much into python, but what exactly is ""wrong" with this code? As in, what output are you currently getting? I believe, to start, you have to wrap your data in the form of an array. So, data: {value1: "value", value2: 2} etc.

Comment: When I run this, I am getting this error: jquery-1.11.2.js:9659 POST http://127.0.0.1:5005/wordQuery 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Comment: is your parameter for the url correct?  I don't think it is.  What is the full url to server the ajax request?

Comment: @mister-positive Sorry I didn't understand. I wrote the url in .js file as `url: /wordQuery`. You mean that this is wrong?

Comment: in your ajax declaration you have set it up as a post, which means it will send the request and data ( assuming the form.serialize works ) to the url /wordQuery.  Is there something listening to respond to that?

Comment: To respond that, there is nothing implemented yet. If you mean like another html to show the result as its response? Sorry if I get your explanation wrong. I am really new to these languages. What I expect is that I can see a result (successful message) on the browser's console as I see this error. You mean I also need to implement a `GET` method to respond to that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `form` element in your HTML. You're probably `POST`ing empty data

Comment: I added `form` element right above the `<div id="custom-search-input">` but I am getting the same error while querying: jquery-1.11.2.js:9659 POST 127.0.0.1:5005/wordQuery 400 (BAD REQUEST)